# Linearity of Groups - does it matter which linear groups we consider?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, general-linear-group

In J. Meier's book "groups, graphs and trees" after remark 3.8 it is stated that

> A group that can be faithfully represented as a matrix group is called
> a linear group.

Other sources (most of the time) stated

> A group is linear if it admits a faithful representation of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$.

In other cases I've seen them stating the second definition over any field $\mathbb K$. But even in cases where the authors speficially mentioned $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$, they still considered groups to be linear if they admitted a faithful representation e.g. of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$. So I'm a bit confused.

**Question 1:** Suppose we found a faithful representation like $G\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z^n)$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z^n) \cong \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$. Does this suffice to conclude that $G$ is linear? I suppose that this is not sufficient, but I can't find any reference in any of my books.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Notice that GL(n, Z) embeds into GL(n, C). So having a faithful GL(n, Z) rep. should entail having a faithful GL(n, C) rep.

Comment: I deleted the first two questions, now it's just one. Thanks for the hint @FShrike

Comment: It should suffice. Isomorphisms should preserve faithfulness so you should get a faithful composite $G\to\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Z^n)\cong\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb Z)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb C)$

Comment: Thanks @FShrike, I appreciate the comments.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  It is perfectly common to consider linear algebraic groups over other fields.  Finite fields, say, or $p-$adic fields.  See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebraic_group).  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Meier's definition is the standard one. You should edit your question to add references to the more restrictive definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a famous result of L. Auslander that any *polycyclic* group admits a faithful representation to $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ for some $n\ge 1$. This is much more than being linear. Not every linear group has such a faithful representation.

I suspect that $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ arises in a certain context in your text, which is different from just linear groups.